# Problems updating to macOS Sierra with a hard drive that has an ampersand (“&”) in its name

Tags: software-update, macos-sierra

I have a mid-2011, iMac 27", 3.4 GHZ with 24 GB of RAM running El Capitan.

When I try to update to Sierra, the update fails with a message:

> Cannot write to null.

Researching this subject, it seems that the problem is caused by the fact that I have renamed the HD and the name contains an `&` character.

But:

- When I try to rename the drive from finder, I get an error: `Try using a name with less characters` (even when I use just a single letter for the name).
- When I try to change the name using command line form diskutil I get: `rename error invalid request 698886`

Is there anyway to change my iMac HD name and to update to macOS Sierra without having to erase the disk and manually reinstall all of my apps?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with just a regular folder using `mv` with an escape char.
It didn't really like it, but it did it.

```
$ ls
Fish&Chips

mv Fish\&Chips FishChips
[1]+  Exit 64                 mv Fish

$ ls
FishChips
```

Might need `sudo` on the boot volume - I'm not renaming my boot drive just to test ;)